# How should I use .sort() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking at a lot of examples where people use the `.sort()` function in jQuery.

So for example:

```
$('#myId').sort(..);
```

By I cannot find any documentation for `sort()` in the jQuery API, can anyone show me its usage?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because it's not part of jQuery (officially), but is a proxied [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

As Derek points out, `jQuery(...)` does not return an array. Rather, jQuery [adds a proxy](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) to make the jQuery object "act like an array":

```
// For internal use only.
// Behaves like an Array's method, not like a jQuery method.
push: push,
sort: [].sort,    // <-- here
splice: [].splice
```

This proxy works because the `this` in a function is determined by the object on which the function was invoked. And, furthermore, `Array.sort` (and `Array.splice`) work on any `this` that is "array like" (has a `length` and presumably properties `0..length-1`). Here is an example of a custom object [ab]using `Array.sort`:

```
var a = {0: "z", 1: "a", length: 2, sort: [].sort}
a[0]       // -> "z"
a.sort()   // in-place modification, this === a
a[0]       // -> "a"
a instanceof Array // -> false (never was, never will be Array)
```

YMMV following the "For internal use only" notes.

Comment: `$('#myId')` does not return an Array.

Comment: Does that mean I do not need to do a .toArray() because of this proxy?

Comment: @foreyez: No. `sort()` will return `this`, `push()` the length and `splice()` a new `Array`.

Comment: So should we actually use $('.elem').sort() since it "For internal use only"?