# Receive list of elements in their visual order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a grid (div container) which looks like this:

[image]

However it's possible that div #2 can be on the place of div #1 and so on. This is done via CSS position, so their DOM order will be the same.
I want to determine their visual order. Is there a `jQuery selector` or some other way to do this?

**// SOLUTION ADDED AS ANSWER**

Comment: You should post the CSS/HTML code for that grid, you could make it on jsfiddle.net and paste link here.

Comment: You can find out index of element by using http://www.jqapi.com/#p=index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(elem).position()` to get screen coordinates for each div. By looking at the `top` and `left` properties you can infer a visual ordering.

Comment: You can pass the divs to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and use a custom compare function that orders first by x value then by y value.

Comment: Done it, see my solution (i added it as a answer)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible. But you could use some workarounds, like:

1. Check the CSS positions of the divs with jQuerys `css()` function and check what styling is applied to each div. After that, reorder them in an array, ordering by their respective css positions
2. Actually alter the DOM position of the elements rather than repositioning them with CSS, using `after()`, `remove()` and `before()`
3. Use `position()` to get the actual visible position. Check this against some boundaries and reorder them in an internal array to their positions

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution

```
$("#grid > div.content").sort(function(a,b){

 var atop = $(a).position().top;
 var aleft =  $(a).position().left;
 var btop = $(b).position().top;
 var bleft =  $(b).position().left;

 if(aleft == bleft && atop == btop) return 0;
 else {

      if(atop < btop) return -1
      else if( atop > btop) return 1;                   
      else { // same
           if(aleft < bleft) return -1;
           else return 1;
      }

 }

}).each( console.log($(this).attr('id')) );
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't include a `sort()` function (or, at least, it's not listed in the API). Are you using a plugin to allow you to sort a jQuery object?

Comment: This is just javascript not jquery - hav a look at `http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp`

Comment: I'm aware that JavaScript Arrays have a `sort()` function. You're not calling it on an array but on a jQuery object, though. After testing it seems that the jQuery object also has access to the `sort()` function and it's simply not documented.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941789/where-is-jquery-sort-documentation :)