# Iterate through children in order

Tags: javascript, html

How is it possible to iterate through child nodes of an element in order?

I can reach all child nodes whit this code, but is it in the correct order, like in the HTML page?

```
for(var i=0; i<element.children.length; i++) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by "correct order". Do you mean the order of the html source reading top to bottom?

Comment: Why dont you alert the innerHTML of the children and test it yourself?

Comment: yes, the order of the html source reading top to bottom

Comment: *"but is it in the correct order"* Yes.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472778/receive-list-of-elements-in-their-visual-order

Comment: I mean, what order did you think they would be in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be the order in which they currently exist in your DOM (whenever your code executes), but remember that elements can be moved around with JavaScript, so if you're manipulating the DOM at all, you may see varied results.

Comment: How can the position of elements within the DOM be moved around with CSS?

Comment: I don't think so. The only way I'm aware of is with flexbox, but that changes the display order, not the DOM order.

Comment: You could be right.  I'll edit my answer for accuracy.